# Исходный код style и javascript в wordpress для Contact form и recaptcha

Tags: css, wordpress, recaptcha, contact-form7, yoast

Можно ли как-то образом перенести стили и скрипты, которые вставляет Контактная форма и рекаптча, вниз исходного кода?
Сейчас на сайте они влезли в header первыми, до йоастовских title/description

пример здесь view-source:https://pokos.kiev.ua/uk/strigka-gazona.html

[image: screeen]